# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object while posting data to db

Tags: php

so I have a simple code to post data to database

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$review = mysql_real_escape_string($data->review);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
mysql_select_db("reherse");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO reviews('review') VALUES('".$review."')");
?>
```

But it's getting me to an error 'Trying to get property of non-object'. I'm new in PHP so It might be some stupid mistake.

Comment: on which line you are getting error? It is possible that some wrong data in the file.

Comment: just a guess with the info you give, but your json_decode is probably failing , thus `$data` is not an object and `$data->review` attempts to get a property of a non-object. Try to echo `json_last_error_msg()` to get a hint.